# monitor a folder for new files

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick-convert

I want to monitor a folder.
If a file is added to a folder, then a bat file should run.
The purpose is to automise things: when a tiff is added to a folder convert it to pdf, move it to a destination folder and empty the monitored folder.

I tried this:

```
@echo off
:loop
if exist "c:\monitored_folder\*.tif" 

for %%a in ("c:\monitored_folder\*.tif") do (

move *.tif "c:\destination folder"
)
)
goto :loop
```

Comment: to just move any new *.tif files to somewhere else, you don't need `if exist` or `for` at all. Just `:loop`, `move c:\monitored_folder\*.tif" "c:\destination folder\" 2>nul`, `timeout 1` and `goto :loop`

Comment: This is a comment for both solutions. When I use the solution of Stephan, then all the files are moved correctly. When I use the solution from Angel115, then I must replace goto moveFiles by :moveFiles. And then, as I earlier mensioned, the files with spaces or date(???) in the name, are not transferred.

Comment: quoting the filenames processes spaces as well (btw, I have a typo (missing quote) in my comment: `move "c:\monitored_folder\*.tif" "c:\destination folder\" 2>nul`). In Angel's case, it should be `move "%%f" "c:\"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

:moveFiles
for %%f in (c:\temp\*.tif) do (move %%f c:\)
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
goto moveFiles
```

you can change the sleep time but don't remove it or your CPU usage will jump to the roof.

Comment: Why not use the Timeout command instead of calling out to PS?

Comment: Yes we could use timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL as well with a redirection to prevent output on the screen. I update my script

Comment: Does the user running the script have the permission to write on the destination folder?

Comment: User has permission. The purpose is to do the action when a new file is added automatically.

Comment: If you want to move any new file juste replace " *.tif " by " * "

Comment: Purpose: scan a foto as tif, save it in folderA, move a copy to folderB, convert tif to pdf and move it folderC, then empty folderA.

Comment: When I ad 4 or 5 jpg to the folder, then only one is moved, and for the rest a loop of "the syntax of the command is incorrect".

Comment: Could it be that in the name of the files there is no space.... aloud?